# Does __dict__ exist or not in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

The first code snippet:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__dict__)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print("get")
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print("set")

    # def __getattribute__(self, name):
    #     print("getatrr")

a = A()
```

It prints `{}` and the function `__getattr__` isn't invoked, which means the attribute`__dict__` exists.

The second snippet:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.__dict__)
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        print("get")
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        print("set")

    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        print("getatrr")

a = A()
```

It prints `getatrr` and `None`, which means the attribute `__dict__` doesn't exist.

Why is `__dict__` `{}` in the first case, but `None` in the second case?

Comment: `__dict__` always exists. Have you read what `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` actually do? https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__

Comment: `__getattribute__` is always invoked, `__getattr__` is invoked as a fallback when the attribute cannot be retrieved "in the normal ways". `getattr` calls `__getattribute__`. `__getattr__` should be called `__missingattr__` and `__getattribute__` should be named `__getattr__` to match with the `getattr` builtin.

Comment: @ freakish, the second case prints `None` for Python3.5

Comment: because you're supposed to return something, not just print

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is that when you define this:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    print("getatrr")
```

you're overriding `__getattribute__` which is supposed to *return* something. Since you're not returning anything, you get `None` for every attribute you'll try.

[Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) states:

> This method should return the (computed) attribute value or raise an AttributeError exception

A viable way to define it is to call `object.__getattribute__` in the fallback case (in my example, I have added a small test on `__dict__` which prints:

```
def __getattribute__(self, name):
    if name == "__dict__":
        print("get attribute invoked with __dict__")
    return object.__getattribute__(self,name)
```

In the end, the hard attribute lookup work is done with `object.__getattribute__` that invokes python runtime.

Comment: How to check `name` doesn't exist and raise an AttributeError exception in `__getattribute__`?

Comment: And how does `object.__getattribute__` implemented to avoid  infinite recursion?

Comment: check if `name` is in `__dict__` :) and `object.__getattribute__` is the real method looking for attribute, no recursion. At some point, someone has to get the job done

Comment: Checking if `name` is in `self.__dict__` will cause recursion, I think.

Comment: `object.__getattribute__` is the real method looking for attribute, how to understand? I don't think `object` has attribute tables of sub-class.

Comment: first `object.__getattribute__(self,"__dict__")` to get dict attribute, `object.__getattribute__` is the method that _really_ looks for attribute. You don't overload/shadow it, because of the explicit call with object type